# Integrating Google Checkout in iOS App

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios4, google-checkout

Am I correct in assuming using a `UIWebView` is the only/best way to integrate [Google Checkout](https://checkout.google.com) into an iOS App?

A fully native solution would be the best fit as I only require the user to purchase a limited number of items that will never change.

Does any one know of existing Apps that have successfully integrated Google Checkout?

Comment: 3 years have passed.. no answers yet

Comment: How about this: https://developers.google.com/wallet/?